# Elasticsearch APM agent not pushing to server

Tags: elasticsearch, flask

I have a server running on a remote computer and have installed the APM agent on another computer with Flask installed. But for some reason I keep getting this error on the client:

`Connection to APM Server timed out (url:http://134.446.25.12:8200'/v1/transactions, timeout: None seconds)
Failed to submit message: '<no message value>'`

Here is the sample flask code that I'm trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask
from elasticapm.contrib.flask import ElasticAPM
from flask import abort

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['ELASTIC_APM'] = {
'APP_NAME': 'mytestamp',
'SERVICE_NAME': 'myapp', 
'SERVER_URL': 'http://134.446.25.12:8200'
}
apm = ElasticAPM(app)

@app.route('/ok', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ok():
   apm.capture_message('ok message')
   return 'ok'
```

The server has no security in place that is stopping the connection so not sure what else to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Helen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the a answer to my own question.

I needed to change the default host when starting the APM server so that it can receive external connections. By default it only listens to localhost.